# GeneralException on insertContentControl()

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I am having issues with `insertContentControl()` for some (but not most) of the ranges returned by `search()`.

Essentially, I search for various terms and then for each find, I attempt to create a content control. This mostly work, however every so often I get a GeneralException that looks like this:

```
{code: "GeneralException", message: "Sorry, something went wrong. Check the OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo for more information. ", errorLocation: "Range.insertContentControl", statement: "var insertContentControl=v.insertContentControl();", toString: ƒ, …}
code: "GeneralException"
errorLocation: "Range.insertContentControl"
fullStatements: (7) ["var v=context.root._getObjectByReferenceId("{4a645…31b06a1e8cb}{205}") /* originally getItem(28) */;", "var insertContentControl=v.insertContentControl();", "// Instantiate {insertContentControl}", "insertContentControl.title="TypeOne";", "insertContentControl.color="yellow", "insertContentControl.tag="someTag";", "insertContentControl.appearance="Tags";"]
message: "Sorry, something went wrong. Check the OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo for more information. "
statement: "var insertContentControl=v.insertContentControl();"
surroundingStatements: Array(9)
0: "var v=context.root._getObjectByReferenceId("{4a64573e-3807-4278-a22d-131b06a1e8cb}{205}") /* originally getItem(...) */;"
1: "// >>>>>"
2: "var insertContentControl=v.insertContentControl();"
3: "// <<<<<"
4: "// Instantiate {insertContentControl}"
5: "insertContentControl.title=...;"
6: "insertContentControl.color=...;"
7: "insertContentControl.tag=...;"
8: "insertContentControl.appearance=...;"
lastIndex: (...)
lastItem: (...)
length: 9
```

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
//This object may contain thousands of terms across multiple entity types
let entities = {
    EntityType1:{
            Term1: [],
            Term2: []
    }
}

await Word.run(async (context) => {    
    
    // search for terms
    for(let entityKey in entities) {    
        let terms = entities[entityKey]
        for(let termKey in terms){

            let searchResults = context.document.body.search(termKey, {matchWholeWord:true, matchCase: true});
            searchResults.load(["text", "parentContentControlOrNullObject"]);

            _.extend(terms[termKey], ({"searchHits": searchResults}))
        }
    }

    await context.sync()

    //add content controls for each found term
    
    for(let entityKey in entities) {    
        let terms = entities[entityKey]

        for(let termKey in terms){
            let term = terms[termKey];
            let searchHits = term.searchHits.items;

            for (const hit of searchHits) {

                //this always works
                //hit.font.highlightColor = EntityColors[entityKey]

                try {
                    let cc:Word.ContentControl = hit.parentContentControlOrNullObject

                    if(cc.isNullObject || cc.tag != appId){
                        cc = hit.insertContentControl()
                    }

                    cc.title = entityKey
                    cc.color = "yellow"
                    cc.tag = "someTag"
                    cc.appearance = "Tags"

                    //NB. this is here only for debugging - it really slows everything down
                    await context.sync()  

                } catch (error) {
                    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                        console.log(error.debugInfo)
                        console.log(error.innerError)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    await context.sync()

})
```

I am mainly testing on Word Online but Word desktop seems to display the same issue.

I just can't find what's causing this. What else can I do to find the root of the problem?

Comment: On a given document, does it always error on the same ranges or is it variable? Also, this won't fix your problem, but don't load `parentContentControlOrNullObject`. You never need to load methods.

Comment: Also, does the problem get worse if you increase the number of search terms or the size of the document?

Comment: Hello @RickKirkham - Yes, it throws always on the same entries.

Comment: I am not sure about the second question... I think yes but only because there is more likelihood for errors.

Comment: OK. Putting the 2nd question a different way: If you delete everything in the doc after the first range where you get the error and then rerun the code, do you still get the error on that range?

Comment: @RickKirkham - If I don't load `parentContentControlOrNullObject`, I get `Error code and message: PropertyNotLoaded: The property 'isNullObject' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context.`

Comment: @RickKirkham - If I remove all paragraphs after where the error occurs, I still get the issue in exactly the same place.

Comment: Leo, without more details about where this is happening, it's not possible to get to the actual reason, and thus a work-around. Since you've been able to isolate a single "thing" that causes the problem could you please provide a [mcve] so that we can look and test? In a general sort of way, it's likely the target `Range` is not able to host a content control. There are various situations where that can happen, such as the `Range` including part of a table or cell structure... You might also test as a *user* creating a content control on that `Range` - that could also give you some info.

Comment: Thank you for your input @CindyMeister. I am going to try to set up a minimal reproducible example, although it probably won't be very minimal... I like the idea of testing it as a user, I am not sure I can do that from the web client though? I'll check on desktop...

Comment: For testing as a user: let your code run to the point where you have the range in question then SELECT that. Then, as a user, you're in the same situation as your code. For a minimal example it could also help to include a screen shot (with non-printing characters displayed) of this situation (selected range).

Comment: @RickKirkham - I have a repro gist here: https://gist.github.com/leoseccia/bef0207eff3bea6bbeb39f0cb1100cff 
The data is hardcoded so it will only work with this document: https://leoseccia.github.io/files/LD%20EE%20Demo.docx

Comment: @CindyMeister - This is just a way to ping you to let you know I created a script-lab gist...

Comment: Thank you both for helping me with this... And doubly thanks to Rick as I took inspiration from some of his code to implement this :-)

Comment: I've got your file and gist. The file is so big that the console.logs overflow the console in Script Lab, so I can't see where the error first appears. I need to shorten the doc. Beginning from page 1, what is the minimum number of pages I need to reproduce your issues?

Comment: Hey @RickKirkham - that's weird... I don't get that issue. Anyway, I deleted everything from section 7 (page 27) onward and I still get some exceptions (168). In the gist, I just commented out `console.log('${i}: adding ${hit.text}');` and `console.log('${i}:modifying ${hit.text}');` to stop generating unnecessary noise. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Hello @RickKirkham - did you manage to replicate? should I open this as an issue on github?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to get back to this. Maybe in a few days.

Comment: Logged this as an issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1169

Comment: this is answered here and in Git. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cindy suggested, I was able to modify your script to stop at the fist exception and find out what's going on. (Good Tip Cindy!).

And this image shows immediately what's the issue (you are trying to insert a CC in the red range, who overlaps with an existing CC, that's an invalid operation): 
[image]

Use the [range.compareLocationWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=word-js-preview#comparelocationwith-range-) API to determine you are in a situation like this.